# What are these folders in the root of my drive?

Tags: ngen

The following folders keep showing up:

1. C:\Default\
2. C:\NativeImages\

They both have a ton of folders in them witha bunch of html files in each folder. I'm assuming this has something to do with NGEN because of the NativeImages folder. How do I get rid of these folders and keep them from coming back? Or otherwise move them so they get put somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: is there no configuration panel for NGEN that allows you to change default locations?

Comment: Not that I know of. If there is I'd like to know about it.

Comment: The Native Image Cache (where ngen puts its output) is usually located under C:\Windows\Assembly, and you are the only person on the internet to have used the text "C:\NativeImages", so I think it might be something different.  Can you give some more details about the contents of these folders?  Anything besides the html?  What are the names of the subfolders?

Answer (score 7):

Execute “Fuslogvw.exe” from VS command prompt (Run as Administrator).
Click “Settings”
Check “Log Disabled”
Click “Ok”

Comment: This is definitely the right answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no configurable option as to where those folders live, then I suppose one option would be to have those two folders mounted to specific partitions on a drive.

NTFS partitions can be mounted either at directory points, or as drives :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create [NTFS junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) to redirect them to different folders within the same partition.  These operate much like hard links in a *nix system.  Microsoft is kind enough to tell you how to create them [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524).